# How to change button's function onclick in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have a button element with function called `run()` and I'm trying to change another button's disabled attribute after one click, to reset the output.
That's the code:

```
function run() {
  let element = document.getElementById("output");
  let newButton = document.getElementById('java runner');
  let resetButton = document.getElementById('reset');
  console.log(element.innerHTML="Hello World! ");
  newButton.disabled=false;
}
function reset() {

}
```

The HTML code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=""
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel' rel='stylesheet'>
    <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, CSS, JavaScript">
    <meta name="description" content="My first website!">
    <meta name="author" content="Itamar Cohen">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="./scripts/script.js"></script>
    <link rel = "icon" href = "./images/java.png" type = "image/x-icon">
  </head>
  <body class="body-main">
    <h1 class="main-title">Java</h1>
    <div class="aligner">
      <div class="text-p">
        <p class="main-text">
          Java is an old language that created by James Gosling who worked in Sun MicroSsystems.
          <br>
          Java is an intermediate level programming language, it's a class based language.
          <br>
          Here is an example code:
          <br>
        </p>
      </div>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <div class="java-tab">
        <div class="inside-tab">
          <pre class="java-example">
 public class Main {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println("Hello World! ");
     }
 }
          </pre>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="button-output">
          <br>
          <button id="java-runner" onclick="run()">
            Run the code!
          </button>
          <br>
          <button id="reset" onclick="reset()"  disabled="true">
            Reset The Output!
          </button>
          <h2 class="output" id="output"></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: **"java runner"** is an invalid ID.

Comment: OK, but that's the one that works

Comment: That's the first button's ID

Comment: Why not make your code a runnable snippet including the buttons, so we can run it? Edit, and use toolbar.

Comment: Which button you wanna change and how do you want it to be changed?

Comment: How to do it? IDK

Comment: I don't understand how setting a `disabled` attribute has anything to do with "reset the input". Please make your code a snippet so to illustrate what is not working for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function run(){
  let mainButton = document.getElementById("main")
  let secondButton = document.getElementById("second")
  mainButton.addEventListener("click", () => secondButton.removeAttribute("disabled"))
  }
  
  run()
```

```html
<button id="main">Click to enable</button>
<button id="second" disabled>Some button</button>
```

Comment: Sorry, but now it's not

Comment: @Coder2826 can you provide more context on how it is not working anymore.

Comment: It's working, I had to fix somethings but now I'm facing another problem....

Answer (score 0):

```js
first = document.getElementById("first")
second = document.getElementById("second")

function run(){
  second.disabled = false;
}
```

```html
<button id="first" onClick="run();"> First</button>

<button id="second" disabled>Second</button>
```

Try this code.

Answer (score -1):

Did you check if you `newButton` is correctly get? Because you have a space in your ID `java runner`.
Can you try with an ID without space? It may need to update your HTML as well

Comment: This could be a comment, but not an answer. Right now you do not have enough reputation to place comments, so you'll need to work on that first.